# MySQL over total memory allocated usage? memory leak?

Tags: mysql, memory

I'm using 5.6.21-70.0 for a performance test. When I run

```shell
mysqlslap -a --concurrency=40 --number-of-queries 1000 --iterations=500 --engine=innodb --debug-info -utest -p
```

to do a performance test, the RAM grows up over the maximum memory usage and never releases.

When finish I `mysqlslap` the memory show use 78%

I have a 1G physical memory and and I do **NOT** use **swap**

> KiB Mem:   1016656 total,   953808 used,    62848 free,    30324 buffers
>
> KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.    41384 cached Mem
>
> PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU **%MEM**     TIME+ COMMAND
> 26049 mysql     20   0 1544156 778316   3992 S 16.3 **76.6**   6:24.01 mysqld

**It seems like mysqld uses about 700M of memory? Why it over the max memory usage? And why does mysql never release the memory?**

My [MySQLTuner](https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl) script shows:

> [OK] Highest usage of available connections: 70% (42/60)
>
> [OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 32.0M/98.0K
>
> [--] Reads / Writes: 40% / 60%
>
> [--] Total buffers: 336.0M global + 1.1M per thread (60 max threads)
>
> [OK] Maximum possible memory usage: **403.5M** (40% of installed RAM)

```
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 274726912; in additional pool allocated 0
Total memory allocated by read views 96
Internal hash tables (constant factor + variable factor)
    Adaptive hash index 4446416     (4425832 + 20584)
    Page hash           277432 (buffer pool 0 only)
    Dictionary cache    1170261     (1107952 + 62309)
    File system         815920  (812272 + 3648)
    Lock system         665656  (664936 + 720)
    Recovery system     0   (0 + 0)
Dictionary memory allocated 62309
Buffer pool size        16383
Buffer pool size, bytes 268419072
Free buffers            1024
Database pages          15358
Old database pages      5649
Modified db pages       0
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 407, not young 484
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 614, created 17947, written 20737
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
No buffer pool page gets since the last printout
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 15358, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
```

my my.cnf----

```
 # Generated by Percona Configuration Wizard (http://tools.percona.com/) version REL5-20120208

 [mysql]

 # CLIENT #
 port                           = 3306
 socket                         = /data/data/mysql.sock

 [mysqld]

 # GENERAL #
 user                           = mysql
 default-storage-engine         = InnoDB
 socket                         = /data/data/mysql.sock
 pid-file                       = /data/data/mysql.pid
 character-set-server=utf8
 collation-server=utf8_general_ci

 # MyISAM #
 key-buffer-size                = 32M
 myisam-recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP

 # SAFETY #
 max-allowed-packet             = 16M
 max-connect-errors             = 1000000
 skip-name-resolve
 sql-mode                       = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
 sysdate-is-now                 = 1
 innodb                         = FORCE

 # DATA STORAGE #
 datadir                        = /data/data/

 # BINARY LOGGING #
 log-bin                        = /data/data/mysql-bin
 expire-logs-days               = 14
 sync-binlog                    = 1

 # CACHES AND LIMITS #
 tmp-table-size                 = 32M
 max-heap-table-size            = 32M
 query-cache-type               = 0
 query-cache-size               = 0
 max-connections                = 60
 thread-cache-size              = 50
 open-files-limit               = 65535
 table-definition-cache         = 1024
 table-open-cache               = 2048

 # INNODB #
 innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
 innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
 innodb-log-file-size           = 64M
 innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
 innodb-file-per-table          = 1
 innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 64M

 # LOGGING #
 log-error                      = /data/data/mysql-error.log
 log-queries-not-using-indexes  = 0 # slow will not log the query which do not use index
 long-query-time                = 1
 slow-query-log                 = 1
 slow-query-log-file            = /data/data/mysql-slow.log
```

Comment: Try setting `thread_cache_size` to 0 or at least a much smaller value, such as 8.  There is no such thing as a maximum memory usage in MySQL. The server daemon will use as much memory as the workload requires. The mysqltuner script uses an old formula that is essentially meaningless unless it shows an extremely large number, which implies that you've set one or more parameters to an unreasonable value.

Comment: i've tried your suggestion, and it still keep ram increasing and never release. so i have a problem. if i have some other application, like web server or memcached.Does the mysqld will keep the ram that other application willnot can have the memory or mysql OOM by kernel if i run mysql for 1 month. or i need increase the physical ram size or use swap like 1G?

Comment: Either your server is not using the actual `my.cnf` file that you think it is, or your post represents at least two different states of the server's operating environment over time. `innodb-buffer-pool-size = 64M` does not match `Buffer pool size, bytes 268419072` ... it's off by a factor of about 4, and I see no explanation for this. Any ideas? You should perhaps `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';` (or thread_cache_size, or anything else you change) and be certain the changes you believe you are making... are actually happening.

Comment: i have found out why it happened.. please see my answer below..actually it's performance_schema memory usage. thanks for you post! @Michael - sqlbot

Answer (score 2):

i have found out why memory leak happeneds.
now i have only 1GB memory and no swap.

the **performance_schema** cause the allocate the memory for about 400M at startup. and innodb will take up to 400M memory usage

so，because of my.cnf use

```
table-definition-cache= 1024
table-open-cache= 2048 
max-connections= 60
```

it will cause high **performance_schema** allocated,
more information pls see

[ref1](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69665)

[ref2](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68287)

Comment: You might also disable the performance_schema completely as outlined here: https://mariadb.com/blog/starting-mysql-low-memory-virtual-machines Basically you add `performance_schema = 0`.